# Are we responsible for fixing items in a our home if we didn't sign an addendum?

Tags: real-estate, utah

We are currently selling our home. Our real estate agent just sent us a list of items that are being requested from the buyer to "fix." We rejected this list and got a response from the buyer threatening us to go to court over an email our real estate gave them with fixing items and prospective dates before we were under contract, that we had no idea was sent to the buyer.

Is an email from our real estate agent, before we were under contract, a binding contract for us to fix those items? For reference, this is a real estate deal in Utah.

Comment: If someone is threatening you with legal action, please talk to a lawyer barred in Utah. Don't get legal advice from this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The state-mandated contract](https://realestate.utah.gov/forms/REPC_2008.pdf) states:

> 14. COMPLETE  CONTRACT.  The  REPC  together  with  its  addenda,  any  attached  exhibits,  and  Seller  Disclosures  (collectively
>     referred  to  as  the  “REPC”),  constitutes  the  entire  contract
>     between  the  parties  and  supersedes  and  replaces  any and all
>     prior negotiations, representations, warranties, understandings or
>     contracts between the parties whether verbal or otherwise. The REPC
>     cannot be changed except by written agreement of the parties.

Emails are not part of the contract. This clause states what *is* in the contract. The buyers could have made a counteroffer (last page) and submitted a numbered addendum, but it seems they did not.

Answer (score 2):

### No, but ...

Real estate contracts almost always contain “entire agreement” clauses that mean only those clauses in the contract are part of the contract.

However, it appears your agent (note the “your”) misrepresented the property by stating (in writing) that certain items would be repaired.

If that induced the buyer to enter the contract, then they have the right to rescind it - that is, walk away from the deal, you keep the house, they keep their money.  Or, affirm it and sue for damages. Recent [case law](https://www.herbertsmithfreehills.com/latest-thinking/what-use-are-entire-agreement-clauses-on-claims-for-pre-contractual-misleading-or) from the UK has found that entire agreement clauses are not always a shield against misrepresentation.

As far as the buyer is concerned, there is no difference between you and your agent: if your agent said it, legally, you said it. Between you and your agent, you are responsible if the agent was acting within the scope of their agency even if they made reasonable decisions that you don’t or wouldn’t agree with. Agreeing to fix items on a property to secure a sale is *probably* within the scope of the agency. It’s annoying and unprofessional that they didn’t tell you about it but it’s probably not a breach of their duty to you.

Comment: For the legal lay person, it might be worth pointing out that recent case law from the UK doesn't have direct bearing on this case.

Comment: If the agent made promises in your name without informing you of them, and those promises are legally binding on you, wouldn't that be grounds for suing the agent?

Comment: @RayButterworth only if they acted outside the scope of the agency as addressed in the last paragraph

Comment: Dude I don't know why you do this all the time. The question specifically asks for a Utah answer; an answer based on "recent case law from the UK" doesn't answer the question. I know your response is going to be that "this site is for answers from all jurisdictions," and that's fine, but then you should start off your answer with, in bold, "I don't know the answer in the jurisdiction you're asking about, BUT, if this question were being asked in the UK, the answer would be..."

Comment: @ColinLosey the US is still a common law country. Decisions in other common law countries are relevant.

Comment: @DaleM ok so this may be a good knowledge swap then. US courts really don't look to decisions from other common law countries. The *only* exception, and it is a very slight exception, is in those states who say that their baseline law was the common law of england at the time those states were founded (so this *I think* is really only the 13 original colonies). *Sometimes* those judges are forced to do historical research into what english common law was centuries ago. In other common law countries, do judges look to decisions from other common law countries?

Comment: @ColinLosey your assertion that US courts do not look beyond US borders is simply not true. The Supreme Court has a 250 year history of doing so https://scholarship.law.wm.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1235&context=wmlr

Comment: @DaleM and by and large, with very, very infrequent exception, US courts don't look to foreign law to inform their decisions on domestic law.

Comment: @DaleM the supreme court looking to foreign law on constitutional issues is another, even smaller, exception. A Utah court is certainly not going to look to foreign law on a real estate contract issue, and I'm certain you won't find any authority to the contrary.

Comment: I wonder if contract law varies substantially between common law jurisdictions.  [I just posted this question on integration clauses to see if there's any substantive difference](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/63586/10).

Comment: @feetwet do you mean from common law country to common law country, or from us state to us state?